# done function not being called in jquery

Tags: jquery

done function not being called in jquery even after data requested

AJAX Post request: `({"name":"name","fname":"testing","ques":"question","sec":"answer"})`

Response from php: `({"invalid":"error"})`,

ie the else part is being executed & not satisfying the if condition.

jQuery Code:

```
$("#askques").on("submit", function(event) {
         event.preventDefault(); 

         $.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};

       var formdata=JSON.stringify(($('#askques').serializeObject()));       
         $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         contentType: "Content-Type: application/json",
         url: 'ajaxphp/askques.php',
         data: formdata,       
         dataType: 'json',
         cache: false
   }).done(function(data) {
        if ('url' in data) {
            $("#asknext").load("quesans/form.htm", function () {
                $("#askcon").hide();
             });
        }
        else if('prob' in data)
        {
         $("#resposne").text("Something went wrong, try again.");
        }
        else if('invalid' in data)
        {
         $("#resposne").text("Enter just the First Name, a word with letters only !");
        }

});
});
```

PHP Code:

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$fname = $_POST["fname"];
$ques = $_POST["sec"];
$ans = $_POST["ans"];
$time=date("y-m-d H:i:s");

if (ctype_alpha($name) && ctype_alpha($fname) && (strlen($ques)<=512) && (strlen($ans<=1024)) && (strlen($ques)>3)  && (strlen($ans)>3) )
{  
// not executed
}
else
{
$data = array('invalid' => "error" );
echo json_encode($data);
}
```

done function not being called in jquery even after data requested & got response from php file, but the else part is being executed & not satisfying the if condition.

Comment: What jquery version are you using and what browser?

Comment: jquery-2.1.1.min.js,  browser- tried both on chrome & mozilla

Comment: There may be a parse error. Try including a [`fail` handler](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/).

Comment: `done()` will be invoked only when your Ajax call succeded, may be your call is failing at the server side. Did you check the status of you call in `DevTools -> Network` ? Try adding `fail()` and see if it's invoked in this case

Comment: This part in your PHP might cause a problem: `(strlen($ans<=1024))`.

Comment: If your ajax response is good, issue might be in the way you're checking `if('url' in data)`, as you're getting json data, see the structure of your response and check for that property something like `if(data.url)`

Comment: even removing the if condition in php still it doesn't work, when i see console in firebug then it says file 302 Moved Temporarily.

Comment: that could be the problem i guess, usually 302 responses will have new location in the response headers so that the browser can automatically fire a request to that new url, but Ajax calls don't work so well with 302 responses, so configure your server to issue a 200 response instead of 302 response :)

Comment: Remove all php code from your file and just keep this and see whether its getting inside the condition:  `<?php $data = array('invalid' => "error" );
echo json_encode($data);`

Comment: @Arkantos, how to do that in hostgator ? when i use the request & response works, but when i use application/x-www-form-urlencoded in ajax type  it gives 302 response & requests for error.php

Comment: contentType should be just `application/json` instead of `Content-Type : application/json`. I don't have any idea on PHP servers, may be someone else can help with that :)

Comment: if you're using PHP >= 5.4, you can set response code in your php like this `http_response_code(200);`

Comment: even if response is 200 the  $_POST["name"] is not getting the value, hence it is executing else statement as strlen is less than 512, how to receive json ?

Comment: like i said you're using `JSON.stringify()` on client side, so you'll have to use either `json_decode` in your PHP or just send the variables normally by changing request data like this `var formdata=$('#myForm').serialize();`

Comment: when i send data as parameters it shows 302 error, that's why i want to use json.. & says The requested URL /error.php was not found on this server...which i never requested for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
contentType: "Content-Type: application/json",
```

Remove above line of code, when using this you are not getting the $_POST variables in your php

```
$.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         //contentType: "Content-Type: application/json",
         url: 'ajaxphp/askques.php',
         data:{"name":"name","fname":"testing","ques":"question","sec":"answer"},       
         dataType: 'json',
         cache: false
   }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        if ('url' in data) {
            $("#asknext").load("quesans/form.htm", function () {
                $("#askcon").hide();
             });
        }
        else if('prob' in data)
        { alert("Entered Prob")
         $("#resposne").text("Something went wrong, try again.");
        }
        else if('invalid' in data)
        {
alert("Entered Invalid")
         $("#resposne").text("Enter just the First Name, a word with letters only !");
        }    
});
```

In your php file put below

```
//print_r($_POST);
$name = $_POST["name"];
$fname = $_POST["fname"];
$ques = $_POST["sec"];
$ans = $_POST["ans"];
$time=date("y-m-d H:i:s");

if (ctype_alpha($name) && ctype_alpha($fname) && (strlen($ques)<=512) && (strlen($ans<=1024)) && (strlen($ques)>3)  && (strlen($ans)>3) )
{  
$data = array('prob' => "error" );
echo json_encode($data);
}
else
{
$data = array('invalid' => "error" );
echo json_encode($data);
}
```

After you put the above code try see whether you are getting any alerts.

If it doesnot alert then un comment the first line the php code I gave and check the console response, you will see an array of variables if its posted otherwise youw ill see empty array

Comment: i did the same, got alert box of prob with {"prob":"error"} as response, it means ?

Comment: Now replace `data: {"name":"name","fname":"testing","ques":"question","sec":"answer"},` with `data: formdata,` and see still you get the same result

Comment: the value of formdata will be taken from ?

Comment: your old code `var formdata=JSON.stringify(($('#askques').serializeObject()));` Apart from the ajax and PHP I gave rest of code is yours

Comment: Now uncomment this `print_r($_POST);` in php and check your console for the array, empty or post variables

Comment: nothing printed except: {"invalid":"error"}, the post in console is showing parameters as: {"name":"chckingdv","fnam... (for: Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencodedDo not sort) & json source as: {"name":"chckingdv","fname":"iting","ques":"queskfn","ans":"ekfnef"}

Comment: I think when you commented this out it should be working fine,
`contentType: "Content-Type: application/json",` 
when you keep it you will not be able to POST, just put the success message login inside your PHP if condition and see

Comment: any link to your page?

Comment: If you put this `contentType: "Content-Type: application/json",` and make GET in both your ajax (type GET) and PHP ($_GET) then it will work

Comment: did this, it's stil the same, i think we need to do something with:        var formdata=JSON.stringify(($('#askques').serializeObject()));

Comment: console.log that formdata and see

Comment: it shows a json: {"name":"chckingdv","fname":"iting","ques":"queskfn","sec:"ekfnef"}

Comment: [Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencodedDo not sort
{"name":"chckingdv","fnam... ] this is also in the console, maybe that from fnam it is chopped..

Comment: making contentType: "application/json" worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is in the way you're checking for properties in `data` object. Change your `done()` like this and it should work :)

```
done(function(data) {
        if (data.url) {
            $("#asknext").load("quesans/form.htm", function () {
                $("#askcon").hide();
             });
        }
        else if(data.prob){
         $("#resposne").text("Something went wrong, try again.");
        }
        else if(data.invalid){
         $("#resposne").text("Enter just the First Name, a word with letters only !");
        }

});
```

Comment: I did the same, but same result. Actually in the php $_POST is not receiving values, maybe some other way should be used to receive value..

Comment: you're using `JSON.stringify()` before sending the request, so all your request parameters will be sent as a json string to your server and you have to parse that JSON string in your php and then refer to properties within that. $_POST won't work because there's no property with `name` in your request, all the values are consolidated into a string. `DevTools -> Network -> your AJAX call -> Headers` and see the form parameters posted in your call.

Comment: what is the effective way of sending the form data as json or as post parameters ?

Comment: it depends, if your post data is just a bunch of key-value pairs, then normal one will do but if you've complex params like list of values to send with a single parameter name, use json